# new array formation from current array in php

Tags: php, loops

I have an array like this in php

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 14
    [5] => 15
)
```

Now I want it to look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [0] => 1
           [1] => 3
        )
    [1] => => Array
        (
           [0] => 5
           [1] => 10
        )
    [2] => => Array
        (
           [0] => 14
           [1] => 15
        )
)
```

Please suggest how to get the desired output using for loop.

Comment: Why use a `for` loop? Why not simply use array_chunk()? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Thanks Mark for the inbuilt function.Actually I like for loop with nested array which is really interesting(sometimes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for($i = 0, $count = count($array1); $i < $count; $i = $i + 2) {
    $array2[] = array($array1[$i], $array1[$i+1]);
}

print_r($array2);
```

Comment: One word 'brilliant'...thanks Michael for your help.The trick is in the for loop ($i = $ + 2)).I missed this part....Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this

```
$length = count($array);
$newArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i +=2){
   $newArray[] = array($array[$i], $array[$i + 1])
}
```

Comment: A minor note but I believe caching the value of `count($array)` to `$length` doesn't do much here. It's a different case when you have something like `$i < $list->length` because then every time the interpreter will have to find `$list` and look at it's property `$length`. Something to keep in mind ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Adnan.It's a great help.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Thank you for your politeness, but I think I'll disagree with you on that one. Check out this test http://codepad.org/oVFpsRdI

Answer (score 2):

Something that looks like :

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($arr) ; $i += 2) {
    ...
}
```

Note that I increment `$i` twice on each iteration as I'm working with pairs of items : int the loop, I'll use `$arr[$i]` and `$arr[$i+1]` on each iteration. Note that this will not work correctly is the n# of items is not even !

The rest should be rather straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Fab.It was driving me nuts..:)